# Error: Cannot find module '@vue/cli-service/generator/template/src/App.vue' with vite

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3, vite

I created a vue 3 project with vite and I wanted to add vue-router to the project, so from the terminal I wrote `vue add router` but after downloading everything I get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '@vue/cli-service/generator/template/src/App.vue' from '/home/frostri/projects/onedrive_local/client/node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-router/generator/template/src'
    at Function.resolveSync [as sync] (/usr/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/resolve/lib/sync.js:102:15)
    at renderFile (/usr/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/lib/GeneratorAPI.js:515:17)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/lib/GeneratorAPI.js:300:27
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Generator.resolveFiles (/usr/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/lib/Generator.js:268:7)
    at async Generator.generate (/usr/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/lib/Generator.js:175:5)
    at async runGenerator (/usr/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/lib/invoke.js:111:3)
    at async invoke (/usr/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/lib/invoke.js:92:3)
```

Is there anything I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `vue` command is from Vue CLI. Vue CLI commands (i.e., `vue add router`) are not intended for Vite projects despite the similarities in project structure. There currently isn't an official Vite CLI command to automatically augment your project files to setup `vue-router`, so you'll have to do it manually:

1. Run this command from the project root to install `vue-router` (version 4x for Vue 3):

   ```
   npm i -S vue-router@4
   # or:
   yarn add vue-router@4
   ```
2. Create `src/router.js` with the following contents:

   ```js
   import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
   import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'

   export default createRouter({
     history: createWebHistory(),
     routes: [
       {
         path: '/',
         component: HelloWorld,
       }
     ]
   })
   ```
3. Edit `src/main.js` to install the router instance:

   ```js
   import { createApp } from 'vue'
   import App from './App.vue'
   import './index.css'
   import router from './router' 

   createApp(App)
     .use(router) 
     .mount('#app')
   ```
4. Edit `src/App.vue` to contain:

   ```html
   <template>
     <router-view />
   </template>
   ```

Comment: This saved me a lot of time. Thank you so much, this should be in their official docs!

Answer (score 17):

I don't know if this helps, but at least works for me.

first I installed @vue/cli-service

`npm install --save-dev @vue/cli-service`

and then Vue Router.

`vue add router`

Let me know if this works for you! Have a nice day!

Comment: This worked for me! I _had_ installed vue cli globally: `npm i -g @vue/cli`, but not in the project I think. (Also I was trying to add typescript, not router, but I ended up here)

Answer (score 2):

I have followed the above steps and it worked for me

> sudo npm install --save-dev @vue/cli-service

> npm fix audit

then add router using the command

> vue add router